# Applying class change to all getElementsByTagName - Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use JavaScript only, not jQuery.

I have 2 problems, firstly I want to correctly apply/remove a class attribute to each *li* element within a *ul*

Ideally when one *li* element has a class set, the remaining do not have a class attribute set(remove if set) - however from my testing when I need to unset/remove a class from elements I have only been able to set the class like **class=""**, which works but isn't ideal.

I have been able to get scrape child elements id's of a *ul* with *getElementsByTagName*

```
<ul id="u">
    <li id='car' class="t">1</li>
    <li id='blue'>2</li>
    <li id='eight'>3</li>
    <li id='nasa'>4</li>
</ul>

var u = document.getElementById('u');
var li = u.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

My second problem is looping over *li* seems to give me alot of excessive rubbish.

```
for (var i in li) {
  alert(li[i]["id"]);
}
//returns
car
blue
eight
nasa
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how you iterate over an object, not an array.

The standard for loop will return only the results you expected:

```
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    alert(li[i]["id"]);
}
```

---

To remove all the classes from them, use this inside the loop:

```
li[i].className = "";
```

---

To remove just a specific class:

```
li[i].classList.remove("classNameHere");
```

---

If you want to remove the whole element attribute (not just reset classes), use:

```
li[i].removeAttribute("class");
```

See all three examples in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/vr9mm2vk/1/

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an array, it returns a NodeList.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, it does. Ok, a node list, which behaves exactly like an array.

Comment: @Shomz Thanks, this works, but how would you advise me to remove all class attributes, is the only way by setting class to empty?

Comment: @Shomz — It isn't exactly like an array. Try using `.splice` on it.

Comment: @gummage You're welcome. I wrote you an example how to delete all classes and how to remove specific one.

Comment: @Shomz Thanks, I was actually using *document.getElementById* inside loop which seems wasteful compared to yours. Also thnx for removeAttribute...

Comment: Yeah, since you already have the collection in a variable, no need to do another query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard `for` loop (instead of a `for in` loop) so you only hit the numeric properties.

```
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++)
```

Currently you are hitting all the properties including, for example, `li['length']`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but how would you advise me to remove all class attributes, is the only way by setting class to empty?

Comment: @gummage — That's the simplest approach.